# Java applet: Can I communicate over serial with the server?

Tags: java, web-applications, serial-port, processing, rxtx

I have written a java application using Processing that communicates with an Ardunio over serial. It works fine when run from the compiler, but I wish to turn it into an applet. When running the applet(as is) in a browser it just goes to a white box. I have tried self signing the applet already but I know my problem isn't that I am trying to access the computer looking at the applet, I am trying to get to the server the applet was downloaded from.

Summary, how can an java applet communicate with a serial port on my server? (Linux 10.04 operating system)
All solutions will be acceptable, but I need them all linked to an applet. IE: Serial>Intermediate solution>Applet

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

http://henrypoon.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/serial-communication-in-java-with-example-program/

check this out. i used it as a "template" to create my own jar program which communicates with an arduino device via serial. it will need some tweaking but if you understand it you will be able to do your thing. and that comes from someone with close to zero knowledge of java